# How to find parent optgroup to selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following selection box (multiple selection) in HTML.

```html
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="dhsSelect" multiple data-selected-text-format="count"
    title="Selected All..." name="dhsSelect">
    <optgroup data-max-options="1" id="top">
        <option value="T5">Top 5</option>
        <option value="T10">Top 10</option>
        <option value="T20">Top 20</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="filter">
        <option value="1">&lt; 10</option>
        <option value="2">10 - 20</option>
        <option value="3">&ge; 20</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

And the following JS file

```
$("#dhsSelect").change(function() {
    // if any item in the top optgroup (id='top') is being selected, do something
    // if any item in the second optgroup (id='bottom') is bring selected, do something
});
```

I am trying to work on the `if` condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Loop over `$(this).find('option:selected')` then get the `closest('optgroup')` for each one and read its `id`. However it makes much more sense to avoid this problem and split the groups in to two selects, as they perform different actions. Having `multiple` makes no sense there, as you can select `Top 5` and `Top 20` - which is redundant.

Comment: I tried the closest('optgroup') but it returns only one optgroup. However it is a multiselect so it is possible that there are more than items comes from 2 optgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

Change `map` to forEach and return to your function and remove the console log - I’m just giving you the tools, the lack of details in your question results in lack of details in my answer

```js
$("#dhsSelect").on("change", function() {
  console.log(
    $("option", this).map(function() {
      if (this.selected) return this.value + " " + this.closest("optgroup").id
    }).get()
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="dhsSelect" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" title="Selected All..." name="dhsSelect">
  <optgroup data-max-options="1" id="top">
    <option value="T5">Top 5</option>
    <option value="T10">Top 10</option>
    <option value="T20">Top 20</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="filter">
    <option value="1">&lt; 10</option>
    <option value="2">10 - 20</option>
    <option value="3">&ge; 20</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is a multiselect so it is possible that it return multiple results.

Comment: It does! Try it! I just show the values, change map to forEach and the return to call your thing - you do not have enough details for me to give a much better example...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way:

```js
$(function(){ // load
var dhsSelect = $('#dhsSelect');
dhsSelect.on('change', function(){
  console.clear(); // remove upon deployment
  dhsSelect.find(':selected').each(function(){
    var p = $(this).parent();
    // just showing we got the correct parent
    console.log(p.attr('id'))
  }); 
});
}); // end load
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="dhsSelect" multiple data-selected-text-format="count"
    title="Selected All..." name="dhsSelect">
    <optgroup data-max-options="1" id="top">
        <option value="T5">Top 5</option>
        <option value="T10">Top 10</option>
        <option value="T20">Top 20</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="filter">
        <option value="1">&lt; 10</option>
        <option value="2">10 - 20</option>
        <option value="3">&ge; 20</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: How about selecting multiple items? Your code always reports `top`.